# Pulling data from a dataframe column only if it contains a certain value

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

Fairly new to programming in R,
I have a dataframe from which I am trying to create a more concise table by pulling the entire row only if it contains a certain name in the "name" column. The names are all in a separate text document. Any suggestions?

I tried:

```
refGenestable <- dbGetQuery(con, "select row_names, name, chrom, strand, txStart, txEnd from refGene where name in c_Gene")
```

where c_Gene is the list of names I need to test that I have turned into a dataframe. I also tried turning into a list of strings and iterating through that but also had problems with that

Edit: 
sorry for confusion I'm still learning! I created dataframe ("refGenestable") in R (but yes it is from SQL database) but I want to narrow it down more now to only include rows that contain same name as names I have in a text file, c_Genes, where each name is separated by \n. I created a list out of this file

Comment: Are you connecting to a SQL database or do you have a data frame in R? If it is in R, then `your_data[your_data$name %in% c_Gene, ]`. If you want SQL to do the filtering then SQL has no idea about an R object named `c_Gene`, so you'll need to use `paste` to build a query with the actual values.

Comment: Something like `c_gene_string = paste(c_gene, collapse = "', '")`, `qry = sprintf("select row_names, name, chrom ... where name in ('%s')", c_gene_string)`, then `dbGetQuery(con, qry)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a few issues here. It's hard to know exactly what you need because it's unclear what the structure of your data is.

The general question is easy to answer.

Provided you have a data frame, and you want a new one with only names that are in a vector, you can use `DF[DF$name %in% <some vector>)`  or with dplyr `filter(DF, name %in% <some vector>)`.  You can't use `%in%` to test whether something is in a data though. You have to actually extract the variable in the other data frame.

If the names you want to keep are lines in a text file, then you're also asking a question about how to get the text file into R, in which case it's `my_vector <- readLines("path to file")`. The actual code will depend on the structure of the file, but if each element is on a new line, that will do what you want.

If the names you want to keep are in another data frame, then you need to extract them as a vector in order to use `%in%`,  i.e., `filter(DF, name, name %in% OTHERDF$name)`

EDIT:
From your edit to the question, my answer should likely work for you. Though, again, we don't know for sure what the structure of your data is without seeing it (you can provide it by pasting the output of `dput(<your object>)`. Here's the answer above, using the names for objects that you've described.

```
gene_names <- readLines("c_Genes")
# is that really the name? No extension? Is it in your working directory?
# if not, you need to use a relative or absolute path for c_Genes

genes_you_want <- refGenestable[refGenestable$name %in% gene_names,]
# is the column with the gene name called name? 
# don't forget the comma at the end

# or with dplyr
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)

genes_you_want <- filter(refGenestable, name %in% gene_names)
```

Comment: It looks like OP is using a database connection, not a data frame. When it's hard to know what OP's problem is because data structures are unclear, comment to get clarification.

Comment: I added an edit, apologies for confusion! Newbie here

Comment: From your edit, it sounds like my answer will solve your problem. Does it work for you?

Comment: @Gregor sometimes (often), new users don't have the skills or knowledge to adequately describe the structure of their data. I will sometimes answer based on my best guess and the title of the question. I've been told it's helpful. If it turns out that my guess at the structure is wrong, I can delete or edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I used to do that too. If you keep it up, I think you'll find it's quite inefficient. The main purpose of Comments on the site is to ask clarifying questions so you don't end up sinking time into answers that turn out to be irrelevant.